# TypeError: 'module' object is not callable Django 3 render function

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-3.0

I am just making a simple hello world page in my Django 3 Application I am getting error

```
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Here is the error

```
TypeError at /
'module' object is not callable
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/
Django Version: 3.0.11
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
'module' object is not callable
Exception Location: C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site- packages\django\template\context.py in bind_template, line 246
Python Executable:  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\Shared\Python37_64\python.exe
Python Version: 3.7.8
Python Path:    
['C:\\Users\\admin\\Repositories\\django-docker\\django-portal-base\\app',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
'Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\python37.zip',
'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual 
Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\DLLs',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64',
 'C:\\Users\\admin\\AppData\\Roaming\\Python\\Python37\\site-packages',
 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual '
 'Studio\\Shared\\Python37_64\\lib\\site-packages']
 Server time:   Thu, 14 Jan 2021 19:15:32 +0000
```

It was working before but suddenly not working now. Here is my `views.py`

```
from django.shortcuts import render
# from django.http import HttpResponse
# from django.template import RequestContext, loader
# from django.template import Context

def index(request):
    """Placeholder index view"""
    print('XXXX')
    return render(request, 'hello_world/index.html')
    #return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')

def test(request):
    context = {'foo': 'bar'}
    return render(request, 'hello_world/index.html', context)
```

The error is in line `return render(request, 'hello_world/index.html')` but when I change it to `return HttpResponse('Hello, World!')` it works fine.

My html file is very simple `index.html`

```
<h3> MY DJANGO APP</h3>
```

The html file is also in the correct folder `templates/hello_world/index.html`

settings

```
BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))
TEMPLATES = [
{
    'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
    'DIRS': [os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates')],
    'APP_DIRS': False,
    'OPTIONS': {
        'context_processors': [
            'django.template.context_processors.debug',
            'django.template.context_processors.request',
            'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',
            'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            'django.contrib.sessions'
        ],
    },
},
]
```

Comment: render is having problems locating ```hello_world/index.html```. You should check your ```settings.py``` for the TEMPLATES variable and see if the path matches your template folder location.

Comment: @Johnson Thank you but I don't think it has something to do with the path. It is correct and if I intentionally put a incorrect path the error would be TemplateDoesNotExist  which is not the case

Comment: @jackhammer013 It is likely an issue related to template context processors. [See Line 246](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.11/django/template/context.py#L246), it runs template context processors. Probably because a context processor is not callable. Please post your `TEMPALTES` setting.

Comment: @xyres not sure if there is problem with my settings but I posted it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`django.contrib.sessions` is not a callable object, hence it's not a valid context processor.

In fact, it's an app and, so, it should be in your `INSTALLED_APPS` list, not in the `TEMPALTES` `context_processors` list. Removing it from there should fix this issue.

---

**Why is this happening?**

The exception mentions that it is happening in `django/template/context.py` line 246 (in Django v3.0.11). If you [see the source code at line 246](https://github.com/django/django/blob/3.0.11/django/template/context.py#L246), you can see that at this line Django is running the registered template context processors. Since, `django.contrib.sessions` is not a callable object, but a module, you get this exception message: `'module' object is not callable`.

Comment: Woah. It worked! Thank you much and for explaining me about the error. I did not what is happening. Also maybe I put that django.contrib.sessions by mistake. You saved me a lot of time. Thanks!